# Can a binary search tree be skewed?

Tags: binary-search-tree

What I am trying to ask is whether a binary search tree is self-blancing or if it can also become skewed?

I tried looking for an unbalanced binary search tree and could not really find anything.
So is a BST different from a self-balancing BST?

Comment: Balanced trees are e.g. [AVL-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) and [Red-Black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). A normal binary search tree can in worst case degenerate to a linked list. Just think about what happens when you insert a sequence of numbers in ascending or descending order. And yes, the implementation certainly differs otherwise they would behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

> is a BST different from a self-balancing BST?

Self-balancing binary search trees are binary search trees which have logic added to them for keeping the tree more or less balanced.

So every self-balancing BST is a BST, but not every BST is self-balancing.

In fact, with a binary search tree we can refer to a data structure without any algorithm that goes with it. For instance:

```
               4
              / \
             2   8
              \
               3
```

This represents a binary search tree. Nothing more needs to be said about how you would insert or delete a node. It might even be immutable, not allowing any insertions or deletions. It still is a binary search tree.

> Can a binary search tree be skewed?

Yes. The following is a valid binary search tree, although not one that will allow for efficient look-ups:

```
                     5
                    /
                   4
                  /
                 3
                /
               2
              /
             1
```

A self-balancing binary search tree, is one that has specific algorithms associated with it for insertion and deletion that will include rebalancing logic.

There are many different self-balancing binary search trees:

- [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)
- [Red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)

  Variants:

  - [AA tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_tree)
- [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)

  Variants:

  - [B+ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree)
- [Splay tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree)
- [Treap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap)
- [Scapegoat tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapegoat_tree)
- [Tango tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tango_tree)